# Elimination property on scheme morphisms locally of finite type

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I was trying to prove the following scheme morphism exercise. If $f: X \rightarrow Y, g: Y \rightarrow Z $ are such that $g \circ f $ is locally of finite type then $f$ is locally of finite type. I believe such a property on morphisms is called elimination otherwise I will edit this post.

I understand how to prove the case where all the schemes are affine. It comes down to a commutative algebra exercise. I wanted to reduced to this case by using the fact that being locally of finite type is local on the target. However, I believe this only lets me assume that the intermediate scheme $Y$ is affine.

When trying to apply the definition, I start with an affine open $U \subseteq Y $ and I am struggling to find an affine open on $Z$ such that $U$ is contained in its preimage.I tried writing $U= \cup[ U \cap g^{-1}(Z_i)]$ where the $Z_i$ are the affine open cover on $Z$ but then I am not sure if this helps.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think you are close. Try starting with an affine cover of $Z$ by $V_i$, covering $Y$ with $g^{-1}(V_i),$ refining the cover to an affine cover $U_i$ and then covering $X$ with $f^{-1}(U_i)$. I think this works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was starting with a cover in $Y$ which was problematic. Starting with an affine open cover in $Z$ as you suggested did the trick when I split up the $g^{-1}(V_i) $ into affine open subsets and used this cover to prove the required property since testing on any given affine open is enough for the property.